# Don't get a usable XML string with .tostring when using xml.etree.ElementTree in python

Tags: python, xml, python-requests, elementtree

I've tried a lot, but I haven't found a working solution to my problem, so I hope you can help me:

I am about to write a python module, which sends an XML request to a DNS server, receives an XML as response and should process this response. However, I am already failing in sending the request.

I have an XML base structure which I want to fill with different elements depending on the action to be performed on the DNS.
For this purpose I read in an XML string with [.fromstring](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring), edit the xml object and want to send it back to the server with [.tostring](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring). The problem is that [.tostring](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring) does not return a usable xml string. The following example shows what I mean:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests   

headers = {'HeaderSOAP': 'SOAPAction:urn:QIPServices#getEntry'}
body = """<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
            instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
            xmlns:urn="urn:QIPServices">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
               <urn:getEntry soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                <login xsi:type="xsd:string">USERNAME</login>
                <password xsi:type="xsd:string">PASSWD</password>
                <sharedsecret xsi:type="xsd:string">SECRET</sharedsecret>
                <VPN xsi:type="xsd:string">VPN</VPN>
                <IPoderName xsi:type="xsd:string">IPorFQDN</IPoderName>
               </urn:getEntry>
            </soapenv:Body>
         </soapenv:Envelope>
        """
root = ET.fromstring(body)
ThatsTheProblem = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf-8')
print(ThatsTheProblem)
```

returns:

```
b'<ns0:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   
xmlns:ns1="urn:QIPServices" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
instance">\n                <ns0:Header />\n                <ns0:Body>\n                   
<ns1:getEntry 
 ns0:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">\n                    
<login xsi:type="xsd:string">USERNAME</login>\n                    <password 
xsi:type="xsd:string">PASSWD</password>\n                    <sharedsecret 
xsi:type="xsd:string">SECRET</sharedsecret>\n                    <VPN 
xsi:type="xsd:string">VPN</VPN>\n                    <IPoderName 
xsi:type="xsd:string">IPorFQDN</IPoderName>\n                   
</ns1:getEntry>\n                </ns0:Body>\n             </ns0:Envelope>'
```

Without having changed anything, the import and output not only changed the complete formatting, there are also whitespaces everywhere in the file. When I send this XML to the server using
`response = requests.post(url,data=ThatsTheProblem, headers=headers)`
I get the following answer:

> Application failed during request deserialization: Unresolved prefix \'xsd\' for attribute value \'xsd:string\'\n

Which I attribute to the problem I described at the beginning.

If anyone has a solution to this problem I would be very grateful.

Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: Python doesn't provide much good way to interface with XML files - I'd recommend using an external library. [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) is a very good one, I've found, that allows you to parse XML files into python dictionaries and vice versa - which might help with the formatting problems you're having with the way you're doing it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll find out about the library. But I would prefer to find a way without external libraries.@superbird

Comment: I suspect the problem here is that ElementTree is removing the xsd namespace declaration, perhaps because it believes that it is not used.  You could test this by inserting the declaration (`xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`) into the root element before sending.  If that is the problem you may need to use another library - [lxml](https://lxml.de) has a similar API to ElementTree but preserves the declaration when serialising (python 3.7 / lxml 4.2.3).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I already tried it with the library that suggested superbird and it works great. Either way, I'll have to use an external library. And with xmltodict it works perfectly @snakecharmerb